# Get wp_scripts()->queue frontend scripts listed in admin

Tags: wordpress

I am looking for a list of all enqueued scripts for the frontend from within an admin module.  I am using the wp_scripts()->queue function, which seems to be what I am looking for, however, it gives me a list depending on the page, so the admin returns all the admin scripts.

this is the frontend output:
[image]

and this is the backend:
[image]

So, I need to be able to get the list from the first image while in the backend.  Has anyone done anything like this before?